# DialogFragment (с DatePickerDialog-ом) отображается как Fragment (а не как Dialog), а onCreateDialog и onViewCreated в логах не срабатывают

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, dialogfragment, navigationcontroller

DatePickerDialogFragment не открывается как диалог. Вместо этого открывается какбы новый пустой белый фрагмент во весь экран (с кнопкой назад в тулбаре), а onCreateDialog и onViewCreated в логах не срабатывают. Может у кого-то будут идеи, в чем причина?

**UPDATE**: оверрайднул onCreate и прописал в нем `showsDialog = true`, теперь сам datePicker отображается как диалог (и onCreateDialog начал срабатывать), но на фоне все того же нового пустого фрагмента (а должен отображаться на фоне основного EditTransacionFragment), и при закрытии диалога остается фоновый пустой фрагмент. Не помогло. Буду благодарен за любые подсказки.

**UPDATE** Также пробовал задавать окну размеры wrap_content вот таким образом: `dialog?.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` в onCreate и других методах, эффекта нет.

DialogFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DatePickerDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private val viewModel: DatePickerViewModel by viewModels()
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy", Locale.getDefault()) 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("LOGS onCreate vizvan")
        showsDialog = true // UPDATE добавил onCreate с вот этой строкой
    }    

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("LOGS onCreateDialog vizvan")

        val dateString = viewModel.dateFormatted
        val dateFormatted = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy", Locale.getDefault()).parse(dateString)
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = dateFormatted
        val todayYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val todayMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val todayDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(), 0, 
            { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                val newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                newCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                newCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                newCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                val newDateString = sdf.format(newCalendar.timeInMillis)
                viewModel.onDateChosen(newDateString) // это послать в навигейтБэкк уид резалт
//                this.dismiss()
            }, todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("LOGS onViewCreated vizvan")

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.datePickerEvent.collect {
                when (it) {
                    is DatePickerViewModel.DatePickerEvent.NavigateBackWithResult -> {
                        setFragmentResult("date_request", bundleOf("date_result" to it.dateFormatted))
                    }
                }.exhaustive
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class DatePickerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repo: FinRepository,
    @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    var dateFormatted = state.get<String>("dateFormatted") ?: ""

    private val datePickerEventChannel = Channel<DatePickerEvent>()
    val datePickerEvent = datePickerEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    fun onDateChosen(dateFormatted: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        datePickerEventChannel.send(DatePickerEvent.NavigateBackWithResult(dateFormatted))
    }

    sealed class DatePickerEvent {
        data class NavigateBackWithResult(val dateFormatted: String) : DatePickerEvent()
    }
}
```

in Main Fargment:

```
class EditTransactionFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_edit_transaction) {
    // variables
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // other code
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.editTransactionEvent.collect {
                when (it) {
                    is EditTransactionViewModel.EditTransactionEvent.NavigateToChooseCategoryScreen -> {
                        val action = EditTransactionFragmentDirections.actionGlobalChooseCategoryDialogFragment(it.catName)
                        findNavController().navigate(action) // здесь навигация на другой диалог, работает нормально.
                    }
                    is EditTransactionViewModel.EditTransactionEvent.NavigateToDatePickerDialog -> {
                        val action = EditTransactionFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDatePickerDialogFragment(it.dateFormatted)
                        findNavController().navigate(action) // а здесь навигация на DatePickerDialog с которой проблемы.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```